# Apps restarting after closing Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I've got a 13" MacBook Pro, first Mac I've ever owned, and maybe this is just standard behavior that I'm not used to.

Whenever I close my laptop, then next time I open it, it seems that some of apps have restarted. Chrome, for instance, always opens up to the home screen, all my tabs gone, and gives me an option to restore previously opened pages. I thought that was odd (I was used to this behavior after reboots on my ubuntu, but not after sleeping,) but didn't worry too much since restoring works fine.

Now I've noticed, however, that it even happens with productivity apps. Gimp in particular spawned a new instance (/window) after opening the machine, the old instance gone. I've also lost work that was left open but unsaved. Sure, maybe that's bad practice, but this is totally unexpected behavior.

Is this a setting somewhere?

Comment: Are you simply closing the lid of the MacBook to put it into sleep or something else?

Comment: The behavior you're experiencing seems consistent with logging out with the "Reopen windows when logging back in" option checked

Comment: @slightly_toasted But I never log out, it only sleeps. And, if I were to uncheck that, what would the expected behavior be?

Comment: Unchecking that option would cause apps that were open on logout to not reopen on next login. I'm not saying you're logging out, but shutting the lid is caused it to behave similarly to a logout. Does this issue still happen if you have the laptop sleep without closing the lid? To do this go to Apple log on top left -> Sleep